# VBA Function use of `isMissing()` in conditional statement

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as follows:

```
Function myFunc(Optional i) As Integer
    If IsMissing(i) Or i = 1 Then
        myFunc = 1
    Else
        myFunc = 0
    End If
End Function
```

It returns `#VALUE!` if the function is called without parameter `myFunc()`.

Because of that I have to use the more complicated code:

```
Function myFuncWorking(Optional i) As Integer
    If Not IsMissing(i) Then
        If i = 1 Then
            myFuncWorking = 0
        End If
    Else
        myFuncWorking = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Is it possible to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA will evaluate both parts of your If-Statement: `If IsMissing(i) Or i = 1 Then` will check for `IsMissing(i)` *and* for `i = 1`.

If you now omit the parameter, the first part of the statement evaluates to `True` (and therefore the whole expression will be true because true OR *anything* will result in true no matter what *anything* is). However, VBA will try to evaluate `i = 1` anyhow and this gives you a type mismatch (because `i` has the value *missing* which cannot be compared with 1).

When you use a function as UDF and it has an (unhandeled) runtime error, Excel will display `#VALUE!`.

In your case, the only alternative to the "more complicated" form is to assign a default value to `i` when declaring the parameter:

```
Function myFunc(Optional i = 1) As Integer
    If i = 1 Then
        myFunc = 1
    Else
        myFunc = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that's really an issue, but you could do this:

```
Function myFunc(Optional i As Integer = 1) As Integer
    If i = 1 Then
        myFunc = 1
    Else
        myFunc = 0
    End If
End Function
```